# Why is my code to print from file so slow?

Tags: bash, shell

I have quite a few aliases in my `~/.bashrc`, and thought I'd write a function to print all of my aliases in case I needed a quick peek of available aliases. Initially I wrote it in C# and it was fast, but I didn't like that it had an external dependency so I rewrote it in shell script / bash file. This is the function:

```
# Print all aliases.
halp() { 

FILENAME="$HOME/.bashrc"

# Colors
Red='\033[0;31m'
Black='\033[0;30m'
Green='\033[0;32m'
Brown='\033[0;33m'
Blue='\033[0;34m'
Purple='\033[0;35m'
Cyan='\033[0;36m'
LightGray='\033[0;37m'
DarkGray='\033[1;30m'
LightRed='\033[1;31m'
LightGreen='\033[1;32m'
Yellow='\033[1;33m'
LightBlue='\033[1;34m'
LightPurple='\033[1;35m'
LightCyan='\033[1;36m'
White='\033[1;37m'
NC='\033[0m' # No colour

while read -r LINE; do

    if [[ "$LINE" == *"# Alias section end"* ]]; then
        # Quit after alias sections
        break
    fi

    if [[ "$LINE" == "#"* ]]; then
        # Comments
        echo -e "${DarkGray}$LINE"

    elif [[ "$LINE" == "alias"* ]]; then
    # Aliases - extract parts for colours. Eg:
    # alias gs="git status"
    # Where gs = alias
    # git status = command

    Command=$(echo $LINE | cut -d'=' -f 2)
    Alias=$(echo $LINE | cut -d'=' -f 1 | cut -d' ' -f 2)

    echo -e "${NC}alias ${Brown}$Alias${DarkGray}=${LightBlue}$Command"

    else
        # Uninteresting line
        echo -e "${NC}$LINE"
    fi

done < "$FILENAME"
}
```

I think it is slow because I'm trying to colour code my aliases, but not really sure. C# would print the whole thing super fast, no problem, but the shell script is so slow I can see lines rendering one after the other with considerable gap between each line.

How do I speed this up please? OR How would I rewrite it so it is faster?

example of what is being printed now: 
[image]

Comment: If you mean to execute `AliasPrint.exe` you should probably put quotes around the path/command. The `#` in `.../c#/...` comments the rest of the line. Aren't you getting an error that `/d/Development/codelab/c` doesn't exist? Or is is finding and executing one?

Comment: Also,  would likely be much faster if you rewrote it in Perl, or even in sed or awk...but how long exactly is it taking? I mean, just how big is your .bashrc that this is taking more than a second?

Comment: @PaulHodges apologies, I forgot to delete the line when I copy pasted, have removed my c# file path now. My bashrc is not that big, I have a total of 42 lines and the code takes about 6-8 seconds, whereas C# took < 1 second, so I Think it is slow. I will look into awk... thanks

Comment: Wow. Yeah, that's a long run for so small a file.

Comment: A lot of that is platform-specific penalty. `fork()`/`exec()` is moderately slow on UNIX, but it's *crazy* expensive on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` can handle splitting the input without the pair of calls to `cut`, but keep in mind that `bash` is inherently slow at reading a file line-by-line, because `read` has to read its input character-by-character in order to guarantee that it won't consume more than *exactly* one line from its input.

Replace

```
 Command=$(echo $LINE | cut -d'=' -f 2)
 Alias=$(echo $LINE | cut -d'=' -f 1 | cut -d' ' -f 2)
```

with

```
 IFS="=" read Alias Command <<< "${LINE#alias }"
```

Comment: bash's `read` is definitely slow compared to other implementations, but it's still orders-of-magnitude faster than what the OP was doing originally.

Comment: I totally thought there's no way this will even work... (after looking up `IFS`), but not only does this work, but it is also pretty fast (~1 second). Thanks so much! I'll read up on IFS a bit more!